# How to append each individual ul with class to the closest article tag above it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, closest

**Currently the code is as follows:**

```html
<article id="post-529"></article>
<ul class="post-meta"></ul>

<article id="post-530"></article>
<ul class="post-meta"></ul>

<article id="post-531"></article>
<ul class="post-meta"></ul>
```

I need to have each individual ul with the class of post-meta append to the article right above them. Do you guys have any clues? I used the following function but it just appends all the ul's to all the articles. I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks so much.

```js
$(".post-meta").each(function() {
    $(this).siblings("article").append(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to target the previous sibling

```
$(".post-meta").each(function() {
    $(this).prev("article").append(this);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The DOM **[`previousElementSibling`](http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/Element.previousElementSibling.html)** property will get you what you need.

```js
$(".post-meta").each(function() {
  this.previousElementSibling.append(this);;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article id="post-529"></article>
<ul class="post-meta"></ul>

<article id="post-530"></article>
<ul class="post-meta"></ul>

<article id="post-531"></article>
<ul class="post-meta"></ul>
```